# Constant html element size on any pixel density devices

Tags: css, size, pixel

Is it possible to maintain absolutely same physical dimension for an html element on various devices with different pixel densities? For example, consider a div with dimensions set in millimeter:

```
div {
    width: 10mm;
    height: 10mm;
}
```

Sadly, after testing with different devices I realized this is not enough to achieve what we needed. What I am missing?

Comment: Do you have a way of knowing the pixel densities of the devices?

Comment: No, I didn't went that far to tweak but need to make sure if there are html/css based specifications handling this already (since the dimension in mm means browser should take care of rendering it at that size when no zoom applied).

Answer (score 1):

As smoore said above, you'd have to know the pixel density (the number of pixels per inch) of every device on which your code might be displayed in order to achieve this. You'd need to access a database of device characteristics, which most likely doesn't exist. The browser isn't provided that information, either.

Comment: I don't see why the browser wouldn't have access to the system's PPI value. If it still doesn't display a mm as a mm then that's just a big fail in math, from my perspective.